@JsonDeserialize not considered when using parameter-names
I have some POJOS that I want to (de-)serialize with jackson. All my classes have only one public constructor, with one argument for each field. In order to avoid needing to write all these @JsonCreator and @JsonProperty annotations, I used parameter-names.
It turns out that @JsonDeserialize is not considered. If I add @JsonCreator to the class where the @JsonDeserialize annotation is used, it works as expected. Looks like a bug to me, but maybe it isn't.
How can I get this working without needing to add the @JsonCreator annotation?

Minimal runnable example:
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import org.junit.Test;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Version;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.StdConverter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paramnames.ParameterNamesModule;

public class TestDeserializeClasses {
    @Test
    public void Test() throws JsonProcessingException {
        
        ObjectMapper jackson = new ObjectMapper();
        jackson.registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule(JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES));
        Top top = new Top(new Sub("foo", new Version(1,0,0,null,null,null)), 4);        
        String json = jackson.writeValueAsString(top);
        Top deserialized = jackson.readValue(json, Top.class);
    }
}


class Top {
    private Sub sub;
    private int i;
    public Top(Sub sub, int i) { this.sub = sub; this.i = i; }
    public Sub getSub() { return sub; }
    public int getI() { return i; }
}

class Sub {
    private String s;
    @JsonSerialize(converter = VersionToStringConverter.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(converter = StringToVersionConverter.class)
    private Version v;
    @JsonCreator // if we omit @JsonCreator, we get InvalidDefinitionException
    public Sub(String s, Version v) { this.s = s; this.v = v; }
    public String getS() { return s; }
    public Version getV() { return v; }
}

class VersionToStringConverter extends StdConverter<Version, String> {
    @Override
    public String convert(Version value) { return value.toString(); }
}

class StringToVersionConverter extends StdConverter<String, Version> {
    @Override
    public Version convert(String value) {
        final List<Integer> versionParticles = Stream.of(value.split("\\."))
            .map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new Version(versionParticles.get(0), versionParticles.get(1),
            versionParticles.get(2), null, null, null);
    }
}

Without @JsonCreator on the constructor of Sub, the following exception occurs:

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot
construct instance of com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Version (no
Creators, like default constructor, exist): no String-argument
constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('1.0.0')
at [Source: (String)"{"sub":{"s":"foo","v":"1.0.0"},"i":4}"; line: 1,
column: 23]

